# How to set "topskip" in a tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

In the following example the distance of the first lines to the title differ due to the different height of the test. Is there a way to force the first line in a more uniform distance?

Using `\before upper=\strut` works for boxes with starts with normal text but is not a general solution as it leads to a large space if the box commands starts e.g. with a sectioning command as shown in the second row of boxes.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=XXX]
aaa  \\ aaa
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=XXX]
XXX \\ aaa
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=XXX]
\strut aaa  \\ aaa
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=XXX]
\paragraph{aaa} bllb 
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}

\tcbset{before upper = \strut}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=XXX]
aaa  \\ aaa
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=XXX]
XXX \\ aaa
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=XXX]
\strut aaa  \\ aaa
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=XXX]
\paragraph{aaa} bllb
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: No, I only want an standard uniform distance for the first lines, but the rest can differ (the boxes are not in a raster, I put them side by side only for the demo.)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: This doesn't change anything.

Comment: Since \paragraph (\@startsection) starts with a \par, it will never line up with anything.

Comment: @JohnKormylo \paragraph doesn't need to start exactly at the same position as the other (section titles often don't start at the topskip position in normal pages either) but I want "normal" text to always have its baseline at e.g. 10pt from the title without breaking the spacing before sectioning commands and math etc completly.

Answer (score 1):

What I like about this solution is that the baseline is at the right place, as shown using  `\rlap{\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}}`.

The real lesson is to not use `\paragraph{title}text` inside a `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=XXX]
aaa  \\ aaa
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=XXX]
XXX \\ aaa
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=XXX]
\strut aaa  \\ aaa
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=XXX]
\paragraph{aaa} bllb 
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}

\tcbset{before upper=\strut}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=XXX]
aaa  \\ aaa
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=XXX]
XXX \\ aaa
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=XXX]
\strut aaa  \\ aaa
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=XXX]
\vtop{\vspace{\dimexpr \lineskip-2\baselineskip}\paragraph{\strut aaa} bllb}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]